# Shaded areas not shown in plotly object

Tags: r, plotly

I have built a ggplot2 object that has shaded areas. Unfortunately I cannot get these shaded areas to show up in plotly, when applying ggplotly to the ggplot2 object.

---

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)

#data
theDataFrame <- data.frame(game = c(1.0, 2.0, 1.0, 2.0), score = c(1:4), season = c("2000","2000","2001","2001"))
dataFrameForShadedAreas <- data.frame(theXmin = c(1.1, 1.5, 1.8), theXmax = c(1.2, 1.6, 1.9), dummyColors = c(4,7,9))

ggplotObj <- ggplot2::ggplot(data = theDataFrame, aes(x = game, y = score, color = season)) +
                ggplot2::geom_line() +
                ggplot2::geom_rect(data = dataFrameForShadedAreas, inherit.aes = FALSE,
                                  aes(xmin = theXmin, xmax = theXmax, ymin = -Inf, ymax = +Inf),
                                  #group = dummyColors),
                                  fill = 'turquoise3', alpha = 0.2)

(thePlotlyObj <- ggplotly(ggplotObj))
```

---

The ggplot2 object (with shaded areas) is below

---

[image: Plot with shaded areas]

Comment: i guess plotly doesn't have support for `geom_rect` ye, see [available options = geom_abline(), geom_bar() etc](https://plot.ly/ggplot2/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the shaded areas into plotly via `geom_bar`. As parth noted in the comment above, plotly does support that.

```
# define theX as middle point between theXmin & theXmax
dataFrameForShadedAreas$theX = rowMeans(dataFrameForShadedAreas[,1:2])

ggplotObj <- ggplot(data = theDataFrame, aes(x = game, y = score, color = season)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_bar(data = dataFrameForShadedAreas, inherit.aes = FALSE,
           aes(x = theX, y = 100), # y should be set to some height beyond the chart's range; y = Inf doesn't work
           stat = "identity", position = "stack", width = 0.1,
           fill = "turquoise3", alpha = 0.2) +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(1, 4)) # set limit for y-axis range here
```

[image: plotly chart]

Comment: I have accepted the answer. I have a related question, [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46042358/shaded-area-does-not-show-up-in-plotly-when-using-dates)